# is sso posible between Desktop application and web application

Tags: .net, vb.net, single-sign-on

I'm new to .Net and I have created web and windows application, Is sso possible between them?

please help thanks in advance

Comment: could you elaborate on any common infrastructure?

Comment: simple windows app using vb.net form authentication and web application in C#, after authenticating via window app and launching the web app via button or link it should not go for login page, have to use windows login credentials

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your web app to use Windows Authentication (via IIS, for example) so that the credentials are passed through automatically? That way you wouldn't need to pass any data from your desktop app to your web app.